# Importing UMD built module using webpack leads to Critical Dependency errors

Tags: typescript, webpack, loader, umd

I am trying to build a simple file that depends on a library built with UMD exports.

```
// main.ts
import { parseTree } from 'jsonc-parser';

const tree = parseTree('{ "name: "test" }');

console.log(tree);
```

It compiles fine, however webpack spits out dependency errors:

> Hash: 85004e3e1bd3582666f5
>   Version: webpack 2.3.2
>   Time: 959ms
>             Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
>    dist/bundle.js  61.8 kB       0  [emitted]  main
>   build/main.d.ts  0 bytes          [emitted]
>      [0] ./~/jsonc-parser/lib/main.js 40.1 kB {0} [built]
>      [1] ./~/jsonc-parser/lib 160 bytes {0} [built]
>      [2] ./~/path-browserify/index.js 6.18 kB {0} [built]
>      [3] ./~/process/browser.js 5.3 kB {0} [built]
>      [4] ./src/main.ts 200 bytes {0} [built]
>      [5] ./~/vscode-nls/lib 160 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
>      [6] ./~/vscode-nls/lib/main.js 5.46 kB {0} [built]
>
> WARNING in ./~/jsonc-parser/lib/main.js
>   3:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
>
> WARNING in ./~/vscode-nls/lib/main.js
>   118:23-44 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> ERROR in ./~/vscode-nls/lib/main.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '.../webpack-typescript-umd/node_modules/vscode-nls/lib'
>    @ ./~/vscode-nls/lib/main.js 7:9-22
>    @ ./~/jsonc-parser/lib/main.js
>    @ ./src/main.ts

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'] // note if using webpack 1 you'd also need a '' in the array as well
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [ // loaders will work with webpack 1 or 2; but will be renamed "rules" in future
            // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    configFileName: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json')
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to keep my `js` transpiled files as `commonjs` but I want to bundle `jsonc-parser` as well without recompiling it as `commonjs`.

I've created [a repo on github](https://github.com/jtheoof/webpack-typescript-umd) that show cases the error. Hopefully this can help you.

You can simply `npm install && npm run dist` to reproduce the error.

Comment: Did you check the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392697/webpack-umd-critical-dependency-cannot-be-statically-extracted

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and wanted to share two ways to workaround the problem:

If the consumed package consists of one single module, just like before the [`1.0.1` version](https://github.com/Microsoft/node-jsonc-parser/commit/8b3ab94351c5e63fc46b5a50819ee59f042c4437) of the [`jsonc-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonc-parser), you can add the following to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        // your rules come here. 
    ],
    noParse: /jsonc-parser|other-umd-packages/
},
```

If the consumed package consists of multiple files, one can use the [`umd-compat-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/umd-compat-loader) as a workaround. Add the `umd-compat-loader` loader to your `package.json` and configure the following `rule` in the `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        // other rules come here.
        {
            test: /node_modules[\\|/](jsonc-parser|other-umd-packages)/,
            use: { loader: 'umd-compat-loader' }
        }
    ]
},
```

Some hints on how to properly use the `test`, can be found [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2073). Finally, but not least, the credit goes to the [OP of the workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/issues/60#issuecomment-357656451).

Comment: When using the umd-compat-loader, will the warning go away. I'm having trouble with my test condition, and am looking for a confirmation that I've succeeded in resolving my problem WITHOUT having to test my lambda.

Comment: > will the warning go away. @TheClassic, yes. It should.

Comment: Note to anyone who unfortunately needs to deal with this: umd-compat-loader is not smart enough to handle all cases. In its source code you can see that it looks for a hardcoded string `var v = factory(require, exports);` and assumes certain structures that are not universal -- the wrapper could easily use other variables or swap things.